# ERROR CS0103: The name 'IsInRole' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have this line into my web service project. This is supposed to check if the current principal has the role of Viewer.

**CODE**

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("Viewer")
```

This throws an error like IsInRole("Viewer") is not into context. Please help what to write here.

Comment: Can you add some more context to your question?
How is this code being used, what are you expecting it to do, how do you want to use it?

Comment: this line is into my web service project . this line supposed to check the current user is Viewer or not .

Comment: If you are trying to query an active directory service, then the error would make sense, are you able to post the full exception in your question that is thrown?

Comment: @CaptainSquirrel I got this error from quick watch . I am debugging again to get the full exception .

Comment: @CaptainSquirrel: Umm ... [CS0103](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103) is a compiler error. Is there anything in the question that makes you assume this is about a runtime exception?

Comment: "...not in context..." typically means you have placed code somewhere it's not expected, possibly you have mismatched curly braces, are nested in the namespace but not inside the class or method definition.

Comment: OP, can you find out what type (full name, assembly, and version) `CurrentPrincipal` in your code resolves to?

Comment: I'll be honest @O.R.Mapper, just trying to play the part of rubber duck and extract more info about this. I was completely oblivious to the CS Code.

Comment: @CaptainSquirrel: Sure, me too - I just wondered whether maybe I was missing a part that pointed to a runtime rather than a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

Out of context typically means you have code where it shouldn't be, or attempting to access a variable that is not within scope. See screenshot below for an example of code statement in wrong place semantically.

Another example is declaring a variable in a try block and trying to access it from the catch block. The curly braces in C# define scope, the try and catch scopes are separate therefore, variables declared in the try block are not accessible from the catch block.

[image: out of context screenshot]

Comment: ok . I understood what you want to say . I am trying to correct this error .

Comment: Might be worth adding that "where it shouldn't be" means (in this case) that when you call some code, it should be done inside a method (e.g. inside `static void Main()`.